# In MS Word, I would like to find and replace numbers with superscript numbers automatically

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word, I would like to find and replace numbers in the following pattern with superscript numbers. How can I do this?

10 1 >101 (1 is superscript) 
10 2 >102 (2 is superscript) 
... 
10 9 >109 (9 is superscript)

Comment: [Find and replace text and other data in a Word document - Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ocmsassetID=HA102350661&CorrelationId=c77ab989-39fa-40be-9f4d-c7031c0d5327&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: A bit unclear. You would like to remove a space after a number when the immediately following number is in superscript?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Go to the Home tab of the ribbon and click Find Replace command.
2. Make sure initially both the Find What and Replace With boxes are empty.
3. Click on the Find What box.
4. Choose Format Tab then Font, Word displays the Find Font dialog box.
5. Click the Superscript check box.
6. In the Replace With box type the desire value.
7. Finally hit the Find Next then either Replace or Replace all.

*Above written steps will help you find the Superscripted Value then Replace it with the Suggested One.*

**N.B.** I've successfully tested these steps with Word 2013 & 2016.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or does this not answer the question? The question was how to replace 1, 2, 3 etc. This won't work for patterns or multiple unique values.

Comment: Answer address the question as I've mentioned also,, read the bottom line,,, N.B.  Also find the comments above by #DavidPostill ☺

Comment: Just saying "I've successfully tested it" doesn't mean it answers the question. I've just tried it, and it only replaces 10 1 with 10^1. It doesn't replace 10 2, 10 3 etc etc automatically. You have to do it manually one-by-one using your method.

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 ,,  yes this is how my solution works,,, OP doesn't means automatically for replace in one stroke, since OP doesn't demanded for VBA macro so that Find & Replace is the only option left,,, and if VBA macro will apply then also it will take values one after another,, since are not collective value or stored in TABLE !!

Comment: I am more than certain OP does mean to automatically replace them all (it's a part of the title!). Otherwise there is no reason to bring up the existence of multiple values in the first place. Demanding for a VBA macro is not required for wanting to do something like this, nor is it something most people have even heard of. I do not understand what you're saying in the last part of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can then use "select all" then go to Home, hit superscript, and then un-select it. This will initially change all text to superscript. When you un-select, it changes everything (including the original superscript) to regular font size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).